# How to pass an integer from an Arduino to a C application on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, arduino, usbserial

What is the standard method to read values on an Arduino from a C application?

I have an accelerometer and a few poentiometers which I would like to bind to [Cocoa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_%28API%29) controls, an NSSlider for example.

My arduino is currently connected to: `/dev/cu.usbmodem26431` and I can read the values printed by the AnalogReadSerial code sample in the Serial Monitor.

How do I read from `/dev/cu.usbmodem26431` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cocoa Serial** (Edit)

Three methods of interfacing with Objective C are presented here

http://arduino.cc/playground/Interfacing/Cocoa

**Arduino Serial**

If you know how to establish a `Serial/USB` connection then you can send the values as either string or binary to the Arduino.

In the `setup()` method on the Arduino you establish as `Serial` connection like this.

*nb: using `115200` baud/speed for this example*

```
Serial.begin(115200);
```

In the `loop()` method on the Arduino you can read data from the c application. here is a full Arduino example including how to send data back to the c application using `Serial.print()`

```
int incomingByte = 0;   // for incoming serial data

void setup() {
        Serial.begin(115200);     // opens serial port, sets data rate to 115200 bps
}

void loop() {

        // send data only when you receive data:
        if (Serial.available() > 0) {
                // read the incoming byte:
                incomingByte = Serial.read();

                // say what you got:
                Serial.print("I received: ");
                Serial.println(incomingByte, DEC);
        }
}
```

Source http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/read

The example above is very crude, you can use Serial.available() to see how much data is waiting to be read.

For `strings` you might want to use a `\n` line terminator or other type of terminator as an indicator for the end of a packet (to know when it has been fully received).

It is a good idea to design your own header and `check sum` to ensure data integrity but I don't bother with `check sums` for simple unimportant projects.

As an example, gps systems often send sentences when in string/text mode. If you look up the Arduino library called tinyGPS, you will see one way to read an entire sentence into different variables within an Arduino program.

This is an NMEA GPS sentence, do not use the same header in your projects, instead, design your own. This is just an example of how you might transmit multiple values (int, string, float etc) to an Arduino

```
$GPBWC,081837,,,,,,T,,M,,N,*13
```

http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/

Comment: My problem is more on the Mac side. I don't know exactly how to connect to the (virtual) serial port. See my edited question